# SWIG wrong %immutable behavior

Tags: lua, swig

Im using swig with Lua and have something like the following structure wrapped, which is used for generic vector calculations:

```
typedef struct 
{ 
    %mutable; 
        float x,y,z 

    %extend 
    { 
            Set(float x,float y, floatz ) 
            { 
                    Vector3Set(x,y,z); 
            } 
    }; 

} Vector3;
```

In the structure below im re-using `Vector3` inside another structure and set it to `%immutable`:

```
typedef struct 
{ 
    %immutable 
        Vector3 gravity; 

} World;
```

In Lua, the following is running as expected, and get an error that `gravity` is immutable:

```
world.gravity=Vector3:Set(1,2,3)
```

But if I do this:

```
world.gravity.x=-10
```

No error is generated and `world.gravity.x` is equal to -10.

How can I fix this issue, I obviously do not want to set that XYZ in `Vector3` is `%immutable`

Comment: What if you remove the `%mutable` from `Vector3`?

Comment: I think that's expected behaviour because gravity becomes a reference to a mutable object. That is to say the reference is immutable, but the thing it refers to is not. I'll try and look into a workaround later.

Comment: @Schollii: You got it! That did the trick... Tks a bunch... Can't believe it was that simple ;)

Comment: Great to hear, I have made it an answer so you can close.

Comment: Wait wait wait... No that didn't do it... its just postponing the problem to the next struct in the interface file (which in my case is Vector4)... Im still stuck with the same problem... err...

Answer (score 0):

Remove the `%mutable` from `Vector3` so that Swig can propagate the mutability flag to inner data members.